# How to solve the ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in dynamic format for each ID

```
df:

ID   |Start Date|End date |claim_no|claim_type|Admission_date|Discharge_date|Claim_amt|Approved_amt
10   |01-Apr-20 |31-Mar-21|  1123  |CSHLESS   |   23-Aug-2020 | 25-Aug-2020  |   25406 | 19351 
10   |01-Apr-20 |31-Mar-21|  1212  |POSTHOSP  |   30-Aug-2020 | 01-Sep-2020  |   4209  | 3964
10   |01-Apr-20 |31-Mar-21|  1680  |CSHLESS   |   18-Mar-2021 | 23-Mar-2021  |   18002 |  0
11   |12-Dec-20 |11-Dec-21|  1503  |CSHLESS   |   12-Jan-2021 | 15-Jan-2021  |   76137 | 50286
11   |12-Dec-20 |11-Dec-21|  1505  |CSHLESS   |   05-Jan-2021 | 07-Jan-2021  |   30000 | 0
```

Based on the ID column i am trying to convert all the dynamic variables into a static format so that i can have a single row for each ID.
Columns such as ID, Start Date,End date are static in nature and rest of the columns are dynamic in nature for each ID.

Inorder to acheive the below output:

```
ID   |Start Date|End date |claim_no_1|claim_type_1|Admission_date_1|Discharge_date_1|Claim_amt_1|Approved_amt_1|claim_no_2|claim_type_2|Admission_date_2|Discharge_date_2|Claim_amt_2|Approved_amt_2|claim_no_3|claim_type_3|Admission_date_3|Discharge_date_3|Claim_amt_3|Approved_amt_3
10   |01-Apr-20 |31-Mar-21|  1123    |CSHLESS    | 23-Aug-2020     | 25-Aug-2020    |   25406   | 19351        |  1212    |POSTHOSP    | 30-Aug-2020     | 01-Sep-2020    |   4209   | 3964         |    1680  |CSHLESS     | 18-Mar-2021     | 23-Mar-2021   |   18002   | 0
```

i am using the below code:

```
# Index columns
idx = ['ID', 'Start Date', 'End date']

# Sequential counter to identify unique rows per index columns
cols = df.groupby(idx).cumcount() + 1

# Reshape using stack and unstack
df_out = df.set_index([*idx, cols]).stack().unstack([-2, -1])

# Flatten the multiindex columns
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
```

but it throws a ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow

Comment: Can you drop down to int16?

Comment: i have done it but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Index columns (very similar to your code)

```
idx = ['ID', 'Start Date', 'End date']

# Sequential counter to identify unique rows per index columns
df['nrow'] = df.groupby(idx)['claim_no'].transform('rank')
df['nrow'] = df['nrow'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

instead of stack & unstack. Using these functions you can have better control over columns

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars =['nrow', *idx] , value_vars=['claim_no', 'claim_type', 'Admission_date',
                                 'Discharge_date', 'Claim_amt', 'Approved_amt'],
                     value_name='var'
                     )

df2 = df1.pivot(index=[*idx],
                    columns=['variable', 'nrow'], values='var')

df2.columns = ['_'.join(col).rstrip('_') for col in df2.columns.values]

print(df2)


                        claim_no_1 claim_no_2 claim_no_3 claim_type_1 claim_type_2 claim_type_3 Admission_date_1 Admission_date_2 Admission_date_3 Discharge_date_1 Discharge_date_2 Discharge_date_3 Claim_amt_1 Claim_amt_2 Claim_amt_3 Approved_amt_1 Approved_amt_2 Approved_amt_3
ID Start Date End date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
10 01-Apr-20  31-Mar-21       1123       1212       1680      CSHLESS     POSTHOSP      CSHLESS      23-Aug-2020      30-Aug-2020      18-Mar-2021      25-Aug-2020      01-Sep-2020      23-Mar-2021       25406        4209       18002          19351           3964              0
11 12-Dec-20  11-Dec-21       1503       1505        NaN      CSHLESS      CSHLESS          NaN      12-Jan-2021      05-Jan-2021              NaN      15-Jan-2021      07-Jan-2021              NaN       76137       30000         NaN          50286              0            NaN
```